# How do I call a function in one class from another class? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers

I'll start out with some context.

Making a simple game.

I have two classes, one called BouncingBall, and the other called ASCIIRenderer.
I have a list of instructions to follow, but some of the instructions aren't entirely clear.

First instruction was to create a pointer in BouncingBall called m_pRenderer, and have it point to a member variable in ASCIIRenderer. It wasn't specified which member variable I had to point to, and both existing member variables in there were private, so I made my own and called it Renderer.

Second instruction **(the one I need help with)** is when I'm writing a function for the BouncingBall class to call SetPixel using the m_pRenderer, and with three variables as parameters.

SetPixel is the name of a public function in the ASCIIRenderer class, and the instruction states I have to call it by using the pointer somehow.

Summary: I need to call a class' function from within the function of a separate class using a pointer.

Could someone explain to me what syntax I would use to accomplish this?

Comment: `m_pRenderer->setPixel(m_PositionX, m_PositionY, ball);`

Comment: When I enter that, I get an error under the m_pRenderer, the exact error message is: expression must have pointer type.

Comment: Then you didn't follow the first instruction which said you should create a *pointer* called `m_pRenderer`.

Comment: That's the thing though, I DO have a pointer with that name.

Comment: Well, I can't debug code I can't see. But clearly you got something wrong with the first step.

Comment: Please show some code as David Schwartz mentioned above so we can verify.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the details you provided this is what I gathered.  Assuming the BouncingBall class would get the X and Y pos and call the function foo with
the X and Y values to have the Renderer set.  Also, I don't know how you will
initialize the pointer as it's not detailed above.  Hope this helps.

```
class BouncingBall
{
     public:
         void foo( int posX, int posY)
         {
             m_pRenderer->setPixel( posX, posY);
         }
     private:
        ASCIIRenderer* m_pRenderer;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I have included below shows an example of a class, in this case `Ball`, having a pointer to another class, in this case `Renderer`, injected and stored for later use.

The `Ball` class can then call public functions on the `Renderer` class using the 'arrow' syntax `pointer->MemberFunction(arg1, arg2);`

```
#include <iostream>

class Renderer
{
public:
    /* Constructor and other functions omitted */
    void SetPixel(const int x, const int y) const;
};

void Renderer::SetPixel(const int x, const int y) const
{
    std::cout << "Set pixel: (" << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}

class Ball
{
public:
    Ball(const Renderer *const renderer, const int posX, const int posY);
    void Render() const;
private:
    const Renderer* _renderer;
    int _posX;
    int _posY;
};

Ball::Ball(const Renderer *const renderer, const int posX, const int posY)
    : _renderer(renderer), _posX(posX), _posY(posY)
{}

void Ball::Render() const
{
    _renderer->SetPixel(_posX, _posY);
}

int main()
{
    const Renderer renderer;
    const Ball ball(&renderer, 10, 20);

    ball.Render();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is: `Set pixel: (10, 20)`